# Detect Browser autocomplete settings from the javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way, we can detect the browser settings of autocomplete from the clientside script? Different browsers have diff autocomplete settings.

I want to add autocomplete="off" to the textfields based on the client browser settings of the autocomplete feature.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm guessing access to anything related to the autocomplete features in the browser is a big ass security risk, and a no-no.

Comment: Can't you just disable it anyway - browsers that don't support it will ignore it

Comment: Unfortunately there is a trade off between disabling the feature and the usability of the page containing such textfields. Some users feels it annoyance to refill the textfields. That is why i was thinking of making it conditional..

Comment: @Karan You haven't explained why do you want to disable it though? If it's for security reasons, then user-satisfaction can be ignored, and you can completely disable it.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you google it my friend.....

http://help.dottoro.com/ljdwgiwh.php

```
Example Code:
```

Fill the user name and city fields with some text content, and submit the form.
After that, start to fill these fields with the same content. An autocomplete window will displayed for to the user name field.

```
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DisableAutoComp () {
            var username = document.getElementById ("username");
            if ('autocomplete' in username) {
                username.autocomplete = "off";
            }
            else {
                    // Firefox
                username.setAttribute ("autocomplete", "off");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Fill the user name and city fields with some text content, and submit the form.<br />
    After that, start to fill these fields with the same content. An autocomplete window will displayed for to the user name field.
    <br /><br />
    <form method="post" action="#URL#">
        User name, with autocompletion:
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" autocomplete="on" />
        <br />
        City, without autocompletion:
        <input type="text" name="city" autocomplete="off" />

        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <button onclick="DisableAutoComp ();">Disable autocompletion!</button>
</body>
```